# Multivariable Calculus, Parametrization and extreme values

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, parametrization

I want to find the extreme values of the function $f(x,y,z) = 2x + 2y + z$ under the constraints $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 2$ and $x^2 + y^2 \le z$

The task is to use a parametrization of the two constraints/conditions to find stationary points of f on the boundary.

I don't even know where to begin with this - I can solve it using Lagrange but that is not what we're supposed to do on this particular assignment. Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

From this 3D graph you can see that the boundary of the constrained region has two parts: the bottom of the paraboloid $x^2+y^2=z$ for $0\le z\le 1$, and the cap of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$ for $1\le z\le \sqrt 2$.

[image]

How did I get those limits for $z$? Equate the right-hand sides of the equations $x^2+y^2=2-z^2$ and $x^2+y^2=2$ to get $2-z^2=2$ which has $z=1$ as the only positive solution. The other limits $0$ and $\sqrt 2$ more obviously come from each equation.

We then parameterize those surfaces. For the bottom of the paraboloid,

$$x=\sqrt u\cos v$$
$$y=\sqrt u\sin v$$
$$z=u$$
$$\text{for}\quad 0\le u\le 1,\ 0\le v\le 2\pi$$

For the sphere's cap,

$$x=\sqrt{2-u^2}\cos v$$
$$y=\sqrt{2-u^2}\sin v$$
$$z=u$$
$$\text{for}\quad 1\le u\le \sqrt 2,\ 0\le v\le 2\pi$$

You should also check for optima on "the boundary of the boundary," the circle where the two parameterizations overlap. You can do that by taking $u=1$ in either parameterization. You get

$$x=\cos v$$
$$y=\sin v$$
$$z=1$$
$$\text{for}\quad 0\le v\le 2\pi$$

Since the region is convex and your function to optimize is linear, any optima will definitely be on the region's boundary and not in its interior.

You should be able to finish from here.

Comment: Thank you so much, helps alot! But, how do we go about finding points now then? Do we differentiate partially with regards to u and v and try to solve for them? Or is there some other way?

Comment: @zacdawg: Use each parameterization and the formula for $f(x,y,z)$ to get a formula $f(u,v)$ for each section of the boundary, then differentiate partially with regards to $u$ and $v$ and find where both partial derivatives are zero. Remember to see if each of those points is a max, min, or saddle point. There probably is another way but I don't see it right away. It might be easier to use other parameterizations: for the paraboloid you could use $u$ and $u^2$ rather than $\sqrt u$ and $u$. That would simplify the derivatives.